# SQLAlchemy with Google BigQuery and reformatting string as date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-bigquery

I'm using SqlAlchemy to connect my python script scripts and google from Google Big Query. Below is my code which I have 2 resulting questions:

```
query = '''
SELECT 
*,
PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", date_of_contact) as parsed_column
FROM 
GoogleCloudDatabase.GoogleCloudTable
ORDER BY 
date_of_contact DESC
'''
```

1. The column date_of_contact has dates as a string datatype, I need to reformat as date datatype, Is PARSE_DATE the correct syntax?
2. Can I query all columns using * then add additional reformatted columns i.e. parsed_column?

Comment: sure. YES for both!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, we can use PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",date_of_contact).

The format string and date string must match.

```
   eg: "%m-%d-%Y" "Dec-31-2021" or
       "%d %m %Y" "31 Dec 2021" or
       "%Y:%m:%d" "2021:Dec:31"
```

[Docs for reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime)

2. Yes,it is possible.

Comment: This doesn't work within SQLAlchemy.  when it's in string format.